# undefined object of a mocked json

Tags: angularjs, json, mocking

I'm simulating a REST call mocking his JSON response to give some data to some input.

my mocked JSON is

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "dispatch_type": "tipo dispatch",
        "distribution_code": "DD01",
        "jolly_type": "jolly",
        "vat_required": true,
        "flow_desc": "flow",
        "output": "ouput"
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": {}
}
```

My js is :

```
DispatcherFilterFactory.paramsMock().then(function(response) {
                            debugger;
                            var result = response.data;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType = result.dispatch_type ;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.VAT = result.vat_required ;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchOutput = result.output ;

                        });
```

I'm sure that the JSON is correctly parsed because when I try to debug my var `result` has the corrects data inside, but when the command `$scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType = result.dispatch_type ;` is performed the error he returns is that he can't get the dispatch_type of an undefined

Comment: The "[" at `"result": [` indicates that "result" is a list and not an object. That means you need to treat it as array, e.g. using `data.result[0].your_object`

Answer (score -1):

```
DispatcherFilterFactory.paramsMock().then(function(response) {
                            var result = response.data.result[0];
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType = result.dispatch_type ;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.VAT = result.vat_required ;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchOutput = result.output ;

                        });
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Instead, explain what your code does and how/why it may solve the question.